# CSS hover and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hover effect of CSS is not executing anymore after jquery-action:

I do have the following CSS:

```
#slider-information-content{
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
 }
#slider-information:hover  #slider-information-content {
  display: inline;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

and the following jquery code:

```
 $("#slider-information-content-close").click(function(e) {
     $("#slider-information-content").css("visibility", "hidden");
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
 });
```

The hover effect is working fine. Also I can hide the div with jquery. But when I hide the div with jquery the hover effect is not working anymore and the div is not coming up. How can I change it? And also WHY?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcH7L/)

Comment: can you add a http://jsfiddle.net demonstration your sample?

Comment: I do hover over #slider-information:hover to show the div #slider-information-content.

Comment: Is it similar to dwreck08's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcH7L/1/ (I made a small change to move the close button inside content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, the `visibility property` set through jQuery is getting precedence as an inline style is set.

You can use jQuery `.hover()` for this,

```
$("#slider-information").hover(function (e) {

    $("#slider-information-content").css("visibility", "visible");

}, function (e) {

    $("#slider-information-content").css("visibility", "hidden");

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwYXG/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Setting CSS on an element in JavaScript (or jQuery) applies the value to the element's `style="..."` attribute.

This has higher precedence than any rule in a stylesheet. In this case, you have `0210` as the precedence for your `visibility: visible`, but the `.css("visibility","hidden")` has a precedence of `1000` and therefore wins.

You can circumvent this by using:

```css
#slider-information:hover #slider-information-content {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

However, the use of `!important` almost always means you're doing *something* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery and CSS, which can be tricky.  If you switch to using jQuery for both the hover and click behavior is will simplify the code and fix the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcH7L/2/

CSS

```
#slider-information-content {
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#slider-information:hover #slider-information-content {
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider-information">Hover this
    <div id="slider-information-content">
        <div id="slider-information-content-close">Close</div>
        Hidden content here</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#slider-information").hover(function (e) {
    $("#slider-information-content").show();
}, function (e) {
    $("#slider-information-content").hide();
});

$("#slider-information-content-close").click(function (e) {
     $("#slider-information-content").hide()
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
});
```